# cp runs from command line but file not found from script

Tags: bash, shell-script, cp, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

I have a script to reorganize my directory structure that contains:

```bsh
files=./*"$pattern"I{"$ifirst".."$ilast"}.ext
cp ${files} ../"$pattern"/"$i"/
```

When I run the script, I get an error:

```
./*S6I{001..129}.ext: No such file or directory
```

However, if I echo the command and then copy/paste it into the terminal I get the behavior I'd expect:

```bsh
cp ./*S6I{001..129}.ext ../S6/1/
```

Why would this not run correctly from the script?

Comment: I do start with `#!/bin/bash` and run with `bash script.sh`.Had to add `eval` to get it going. I had to fix an issue in getting it to respect leading zeros, but got it sorted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your script doesn't work the way you expect it because of the order of expansion.

From the bash manual:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion); word splitting; and pathname expansion.

As you see, brace expansion is first, variable expansion is later. In an assignment, brace expansion is not performed. Otherwise an expression `x={1,2}` would be expanded to `x=1 x=2`, and that also wouldn't make sense.

One solution for this, as you found out, is `eval`, because the whole expansion is done twice, so the first variable expansion is performed before the second brace expansion.

Be sure you understand the risks of `eval`, in particular never use it for untrusted input.

As you are using bash, you can use an array.

```
files=( ./*"$pattern"I{"$ifirst".."$ilast"}.ext )
cp "${files[@]}" ../"$pattern"/"$i"/
```